# Configuring Android to use in terminal for Linux Mint

Tags: android, debugging, linux-mint

I am currently using Eclipse to develop Android apps. Following the Android Developer tutorial, they had the option to program using the command line. I am interested in doing it this way but ran into a number of errors. I have tried several solutions available on the internet and I fear that I might have added to many things on my PATH file. None of the solutions have worked for me.

I am very lost with all these directories. Please help for Linux Mint specific distribution.

Key errors to address are:

```
android: command not found
```

and

```
ant debug
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I downloaded adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130717.

Update:

I think I managed to get the android command working by hardcoding the following on my bash.bashrc:

```
/etc/.../sdk/tools
/etc/.../sdk/platform-tools
```

Please let me know if it is recommended to do this another way.

However, ant debug is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ADB is properly in your path, the `android` command should launch the SDK updater. Here is what I have in my .bashrc

```
 # SDK
 PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk/tools
 PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: Please let me know how this is done. I am not sure whether I should hard code this into my /etc/bash.bashrc or if there is another way of doing so.

Comment: I would stick to .bashrc as a beginner. Less risk and no sudo needed. ```gedit ~/.bashrc``` remove all earlier additions. Add like I did above, but with your actual location of the sdk. You can use the ANDROID_HOME variable like above if you want, but that is just a precaution in case you intend to move the sdk someday.

Comment: I ran into a problem where this would not work. But I restarted terminal and it was working properly. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you need to restart your environment. You can restart the terminal, or just use ```source .bashrc```. You should be set permanently now. Have fun!

Comment: nano has replaced gedit in my Linux Mint 18.1 and does the job.  nano ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

You put the environment variable configuration in which files? configuration is completed, use the source command to run the file, or try to restart the computer

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to Linux with longtime usage of Windows. I have not tampered much with my Mint system. Where are the environment variable configs usually located? I am looking these up as we speak.

Comment: Modify /etc/profile file or .bashrc file in your user directory,add environment variable,such as ANDROID_HOME=your android sdk folder,PATH=$ANDROID_HOME\tools:$ANDROID_HOMplatform-tools:$PATH